# Getting back a moved file from tmp

Tags: command-line, mv

I used the following command to move my driver file from Downloads to tmp folder, however, after I ran this command the file disappeared:

> mv ~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz ~/tmp

Now the file is very large and I cannot download it again. Is there some way to get it back? 
Did I use a wrong command? Please help, this is my first question, Thank you.
PS: I was following the online tutorial on AMD site for driver installation.

Comment: Unless you already had a `~/tmp` directory (not the same as the system's `/tmp`) then you actually *renamed* the file to `~/tmp` i.e. a file called `tmp` in your home directory

Comment: oh actually I got it, the file was moved to a subfolder in Downloads. Thank you.